# Как правильно реализовать retrofit 2?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Не получается настроить `retrofit 2` для получения данных с сервера. Тема для меня новая, поэтому пока не могу понять.
Вот пример моей задачи: есть сервер со статическим путем: `http://0.0.0.0/testapi/?`. В нем есть класс `myApi` с методом `get`. Полный пример запроса должен выглядеть так: `http://0.0.0.0/testapi/?myApi.get={"idLine":id}`, нужно получить `json` ответ в таком виде: `{"response":{"title":"some text","text":"some text"}}`.
Вот мой код:
**ServerAPI**

```
public interface ServerAPI {

    @GET("myApi.get")
        Call<List<MyClass>> getData(@Field("idLine") String table_id, @Field("id") int id);

}
```

**App**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static ServerAPI serverAPI;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://0.0.0.0/testapi/?")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

        serverAPI = retrofit.create(ServerAPI.class);
    }

    public static ServerAPI getApi() {
        return serverAPI;
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
App.getApi().getData("idLine", 5).enqueue(new Callback<List<MyClass>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<MyClass>> call, Response<List<MyClass>> response) {
            Toast.makeText(context, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<MyClass>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

К сожалению ничего не происходит, приложение просто останавливается и все.

Хотелось бы также узнать про логирование `retrofit 2`, чтобы можно было отловить на какой адрес производится запрос, а также какая инфа приходит.
Примеры из инета пробовал закодить, но не смог подстроить их под свой личный пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `baseUrl` - должен кончаться на `/`, не на `?`.
2. В запросе `?myApi.get={"idLine":id}` - у вас параметр с именем `myApi.get` и значением `{"idLine":id}`. Последнее это `json`. Его вам надо передавать как строку.
3. Ответ надо получать так: `response.body().string()`, вместо вызова `toString()` у `ResponseBody`.
4. Тип данных в ответе у вас не список `MyClass`-ов, но объект с одним объектом внутри. Никаких списков/массивов не видно.

Т.е. как-то так:

```
public class MyResponse {

    public MyClass response;

    public static class MyClass {

        public String title;
        public String text;

    }
}
```

```
public interface ServerAPI {

    @GET
    Call<MyResponse> getData(@Query("myApi.get") String json);
}
```

```
String json = "{\"idLine\":" + id + "}"

App.getApi().getData(json).enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {
        String responseString = response.body().string();
        Toast.makeText(context, responseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<MyClass>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: Сделал все как вы написали, но приложение зависает и потом все заканчивается переполнением стека. Где посмотреть логи я не знаю.

Comment: @SviatoIa, логи надо смотреть в нижней панели студии - это androidMonitor или stacktrace

Comment: @mohax, я просто неправильно выразился. Я не знаю как посмотреть логи моего api. В AndroidMonitor ничего не отображается.